# Conflito ao usar Gson + Facebook API

Tags: android, facebook-sdk, gson

Fala galera, tudo certo?

Alguém aí já usou a biblioteca Gson em um mesmo projeto em que foi utilizado a Facebook SDK?

O problema aconteceu quando eu utilizei a Facebook SDK para permitir o login no aplicativo através da conta do Facebook. Essa rotina também funcionou perfeitamente, porém ela faz o Gson bugar.

Na prática, estou usando as seguintes dependências no meu Gradle:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

No código, o erro acontece quando eu tento instanciar o Gson, nessa linha:

```
 Gson g = new Gson();
```

E o erro que acontece é esse:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/gson/Gson
```

Já pesquisei bastante e encontrei pessoas com erros semelhantes, pelo que entendi a Facebook SDK utiliza também o Gson, por isso acontece esse conflito. Algumas soluções que encontrei para esse tipo de problema são as seguintes, porém nenhuma delas me resolveu o meu problema:

Adicionar o mavenCentral() nos repositórios: já fiz mas não resolveu.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Dar um "exclude" no Gson do Facebook SDK: também tentei e não funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha... Na tentativa de reduzir o número de métodos para um número inferior a 64K, eu comecei a medir o número de métodos das minhas dependencias usando esse site [Methods Count](http://www.methodscount.com/) e então percebi que essa dependência

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0
```

estava com um número muito grande de métodos. Então substitui ela pelas seguintes:  `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'`

Fazendo isso o conflito sumiu e o problema parece estar solucionado.

Answer (score 0):

Vai no seu arquivo **build.grade**, dentro do diretório **/app** e adicione a linha **multiDexEnabled false** dentro do **defaultConfig**, exemplo:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.exemple.exemple"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled false
}
```

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado por responder! Porém eu não posso mudar para false, pois eu tenho mais de 64k métodos em meu arquivo .dex (segundo o erro que me é apresentado). Vou por o erro em outro comentário para organizar melhor:

Comment: Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html </code>